# How to Refresh the "Uninstall an update" page

Tags: windows-10

Before running "Repair Install of Windows 10 22H2” the “Uninstall an update” page matched the “View update history” page. After the Repair procedure, they do not match.

Is there a simple way to refresh the “Uninstall an Update” page to correctly show all installed Feature, Cumulative, Security and Servicing stack updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some modest searching around and reading.

If you start with an older version of Windows 10 and do a Repair Install, it takes you to the current version when you do the Repair Install.

So 20H2 -> 22H2   21H2 -> 22H2  and 22H2 -> 22H2

So in terms of updates, Windows is starting fresh. The whole system is new but your User Profile was saved and used.

So Windows cannot create an Update History page because it doesn't really have a knowledge of where it came from (that is in Windows.old).

Accordingly, the direct answer to your question *(Is there a simple way to refresh the “Uninstall an Update” page to correctly show all installed Feature, Cumulative, Security and Servicing stack updates?)* is no, that cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do understand

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, and your time in researching your answer. This is my first question  in StackExchange,

Comment: Have a good time here. This is a decently run Q&A site